# php code working finely on localhost but not working on

Tags: php

I am using php script for login which is fully working on my localhost(apache2,OS:ubuntu)
but not working when i put it online

here is attached the php code

```
<?php
include('config.php');
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{
    $myusername=addslashes($_POST['user_name']);
    $mypassword=addslashes($_POST['pass_word']);
    $mypassword=md5($mypassword);
    $sql="select id from userinformation2 WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword' ";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $active=$row['active'];
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count==1)
    {
        session_register("myusername");
        $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;
        header("location:welcome.php");
    }
    else
    {
        $error="name and password is invalid";
        echo $error;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if the database on live is fetching morethan one record for the id and password , can cause the problem because the condition is $count ==1 if mysql_num_rows($result) is greater than one then it couldn't fall in the condition, and one thing to suggest why you are not using isset condition